# Line across any device and in the centre, using canvas or html,css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I'm making an app using JavaScript and JQuery, which will tell the user if there device is straight or not, basically like a spirit level. I want to draw a line a straight line across the middle of the screen and i want this to be responsive no matter the size of the device. This will be used on mobiles and tablets. I used a canvas to the draw a line and so far i'm not sure if this is the right way to approach this?

if anyone could give me any advice i would really appreciate it. Below is my canvas line so far. And I've included some rough drawing of what i mean.

```
const c = document.getElementById("LineCanvas");
const drw = c.getContext("2d");
drw.beginPath();
drw.moveTo(10,45);
drw.lineTo(180,47);
drw.lineWidth = 5;
drw.strokeStyle = '#006400';
drw.stroke();
```

[If the phone is aligned straight the line will be green else red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F5MT.png)

Answer (score 0):

to draw the line you can use a pseudo element from `HTML` or `body` or any specific tag that you want to use in a specific page or click , then update rotation via `transform:rotate() ;` or `rotate3D()`

example ( **without javascript**, rotate values will have to be taken from your device via your app ):

```js
let level = document.querySelector("#level");
document.querySelector("#spirit").onclick = function() {
  level.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
#level {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#level.show {
  display: block;
}

#level::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200vmax;
  margin: 0 -50vmax;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 5px #bee;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#level.show~#spirit::before {
  content: 'Hide';
}

#level:not(.show)~#spirit::before {
  content: 'Show';
}


/* animation to fake phone device moving */

#level::before {
  animation: rt 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes rt {
  20% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 1, -0.25turn);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 0.5turn);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 1, -0.75turn);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, -1, -0.5turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="level">
  <!-- to show on a single page or via js on user request -->
</div>
<button id="spirit" type=button> that spirit level</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a go now.

Comment: That is great, ive just tried it. But the problem is, this is displayed on every single page now. I have a home page before the user goes into the level part if that makes sense.

Comment: I only want this to display when the user selects to use the "spirit level" which will then take them to another page where this line will be used

Comment: @ChristianKasongo i turned it into fixed container that you can insert in a single page or toglle Show/Hide.

Comment: aded a toggle button for an example ;)

Answer (score 0):

While drawing a line with canvas can work you might find it more straightforward to draw it with a simple div element. When you sense a slope you can change its color to red and back to green if it's level.

Of course you will have to do some calculations to decide what angle you want the line to be - but I guess that is the whole point of your webapp to show people how far off they are.

When you know the angle you want the line to be call slope(n) where n is the number of degrees. I've also put in a simple button so the user can choose whether to show the line or not but I expect you'll have your own code for that.

On any page where you want the user to be able to show the line put this in the head:

```
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
.linecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
} 
#line {
  width: 200vmax;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50vw - 100vmax);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color:red;
}

.hideline {
  display: none;
  }
  
#showbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

</style>
```

and put this in the main body of the page:

```
<div class="linecontainer">
  <div id="showbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('line').classList.toggle('hideline');">
    Click me to show/hide the line
  </div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>

<script>
function slope(deg) {
    let line = document.getElementById('line');
    line.style.backgroundColor = ( deg%180 == 0 ) ? 'green' : 'red';
    line.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
</script>
```

Here's a snippet where you can show the line at different angles.

```js
function slope(deg) {
    let line = document.getElementById('line');
    line.style.backgroundColor = ( deg%180 == 0 ) ? 'green' : 'red';
    line.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
.linecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99999;
} 
#line {
  width: 200vmax;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50vw - 100vmax);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color:red;
}

.hideline {
  display: none;
  }
  
#showbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 2em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="linecontainer">
  <div id="showbtn" onclick="document.getElementById('line').classList.toggle('hideline');">
    Click me to show/hide the line
  </div>
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>

<!-- this is just for the demo -->
<div style="background-#eeeeee;font-size: 20px;position:fixed;z-index:100000;bottom:0;left:0;">How many degrees do you want me to rotate? <input style="font-size:20px;"value="45" onchange="slope(this.value);"/></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me out! this is great!.. Many thanks.